# xrdp - only root can successfully connect to remote desktop session

Tags: 20.04, remote-desktop, xrdp

For the past week, I have been trying to connect to a desktop running Ubuntu 20.04 from a Windows 10 laptop using xrdp and remote desktop connection. After multiple failed attempts and hours of reading guides, I was finally able to connect. However, it only works if I connect as root. If I input my non-root user credentials, the session closes immediately after connecting.

I this this is a permissions issue, but I no sure.

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess here.  If you are logged on physically on the ubuntu machine with the non-root user account and you try to remote desktop using the exact same user account, you will notice that the rdp connection will close immediately after connecting to it...  This is a known behavior

You cannot use the same account to login concurrently locally and remotely to the ubuntu machine.  If this looks like your issue, try the following

logout from the local session on the ubuntu machine
try to remote desktop again using the same user account and you should have access to your remote desktop

Hope this help
Till next time
See ya